# Get search path of URL with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following URL which is generated from a search:

[http://example.com/wwn/en/resources/?search_paths[]=/wwn/en/resources&resource-category=Welsh+Wound+Network](http://example.com/wwn/en/resources/?search_paths%5B%5D=/wwn/en/resources&resource-category=Welsh%20Wound%20Network)

I've read about using `window.location.search` but how can i use this with the above url. Basically I need to get the result of 'resource-category' which in this case is Welsh Wound Network

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way too: http://code-tricks.com/get-url-parameters-using-javascript/

In your case, you can use the function in the above url and do:
var resourceCategoryParameter = getUrlParameters("resource-category", "", true);

This should return whatever is in resource-category.

Comment: In general, you should try to answer questions in the actual answer space, not just with a link. "The function in the above url" is only meaningful to future googlers for as long as code-tricks.com exists and doesn't change how their files look like.

Comment: Though I did notice after I posted that, it's likely you did reproduce the answer in the sentence below the link, in which case, that's fine (linking in addition to answering is totally a reasonable thing to do), I would just make it clear so people glancing through know that's what you did. ;)

Comment: Totally agree. Thanks again!